# How to add the automatic line-break in multicolumn cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking, multicolumn, cell

I have created a table, and I have fixed its width, but the problem when I write a long text, the text breaks the line, I want to add an automatic line break when the text should respect the width of the line. how can I do that ? I used template of springier. This is my table:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

%\scriptsize        
\centering


% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table*}[htp]


%{|p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.02\textwidth}|} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|
                 p{0.05\textwidth}|
                 p{0.2\textwidth}|
                 p{0.2\textwidth}|
                 p{0.2\textwidth}|
                 p{0.05\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Players Interaction} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Game type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Game model} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Strategy set} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Payoff} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Ref} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Non-cooperative game} & \multirow{2}{*}{UvsU non coop} & m1 & s1 & p1 & r1 \\ \cline{3-6} 
 &  & m2 & s2 & p2 & r2 \\ \cline{2-6} 
 & \multirow{2}{*}{NvsN non coop} & m3 & s3 & p3 & r3 \\ \cline{3-6} 
 &  & m4 & \multirow{2}{*}{s45} & p4 & \multirow{2}{*}{r45} \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
\multirow{4}{*}{Cooperative game} & \multirow{3}{*}{NvsN cooperative} & m5 &  & p5 &  \\ \cline{3-6} 
 &  & m6 & s6 & p6 & r6 \\ \cline{3-6} 
 &  & m7 & s7 & p7 & r7 \\ \cline{2-6} 
 & User vs Net & m8 & s8 & p8 & r8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `\multirow{2}{=}` instead of `\multirow{2}{*}`.

Comment: Which document class you use?

Comment: @Zarko I used \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, in question always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example). As mentioned in @leandriss comment, for `\multirow` options you should use `\multirow{4}{=}{...}`. Beside this I suggest to use `tabularx` table environment and `\makecell` for column headers. See MWE below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|
                             >{\RaggedRight}p{0.11\linewidth}|
                             L|L|L|
                             l|}
    \hline
\makecell{Players\\ Interaction} 
    &   \makecell{Game\\ type} 
        &   \makecell{Game\\ model} 
            &   \makecell{Strategy\\ set} 
                &   Payoff
                    &   Ref             \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{=}{Non-cooperative game} 
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{UvsU non coop} 
        & m1    & s1    & p1    & r1    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m2    & s2    & p2    & r2    \\ \cline{2-6}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{NvsN non coop} 
        & m3    & s3    & p3    & r3    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m4    &   \multirow{2}{*}{s45} 
                        & p4    & \multirow{2}{*}{r45}  \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
\multirow{4}{=}{Cooperative game} 
    &   \multirow{3}{=}{NvsN cooperative} 
        & m5    &       & p5    &       \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m6    & s6    & p6    & r6    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m7    & s7    & p7    & r7    \\ \cline{2-6}
    & User vs Net 
        & m8    & s8    & p8    & r8    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @zakro thank you very much but can I understand why you used  **\makecell**

Comment: Did not work @zarko

Comment: @BraTaDor: `\makecell` is used here in order to add manual linebreaks in the column headers. What exactly did not work? Did you use the exact same code from Zarko's answer or did you copy parts of it into your origonal document? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @leandriis  thank you very much, I had a problem but i fix it ... thank you a lot.

Comment: @zarko thank you very much