# How to enable the automatic line breaks in table and forced the text to break?

Tags: tables, multirow, makecell, cell

I have created a table, and I have fixed its width, but the problem when I write a long text, the text breaks the line, I want to add an automatic line break when the text should respect the width of the line. how can I do that ? I used template of springer. This is my table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}






%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{table*}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|
                             m{0.2\textwidth}|
                             p{0.2\textwidth}|
                             p{0.2\textwidth}|
                             p{0.1\textwidth}|
                             p{0.1\textwidth}|
                             p{0.1\textwidth}|}
    \hline
\makecell{Players Interaction} 
&   \makecell[Xt]{Text Text Text Text Text Texts} 
&   \makecell[Xt]{Text Text Text Text Text Texts} 
&   \makecell[Xt]{Text Text Text Text Text Texts} 
&   Payoff
&   Ref             \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts} 
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts} 
        & m1    & s1    & p1    & r1    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m2    & s2    & p2    & r2    \\ \cline{2-6}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts} 
        & m3    & s3    & p3    & r3    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & Evolutionary game.    &   \multirow{2}{*}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts.} 
                        & Utility function.    & \multirow{2}{*}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts }  \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
\multirow{4}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts} 
    &   \multirow{3}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts} 
        & Bankruptcy game.    &       & Text Text Text Text Text Texts.    &       \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m6    & s6    & p6    & r6    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m7    & s7    & p7    & r7    \\ \cline{2-6}
    & User vs Net 
        & m8    & s8    & p8    & r8    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\end{document}
```

I want to remove the  breaks line.
[image]

Comment: What's the difference to your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/549369/134144?

Comment: As a bit of background information: `\multirow{2}{=}` gives you a cell that shares the same width as the column the `\mutirow` command is used in. `\multirow{2}{*}` on the other hand results in a cell that is as wide as its  contents, hence no automatic linebreaks are added here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|
                             p{0.1\textwidth}|
                             p{0.1\textwidth}|
                             p{0.1\textwidth}|}
    \hline
{Players Interaction}
&   {Text Text Text Text Text Texts}
&   {Text Text Text Text Text Texts}
&   {Text Text Text Text Text Texts}
&   Payoff
&   Ref             \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts}
        & m1    & s1    & p1    & r1    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m2    & s2    & p2    & r2    \\ \cline{2-6}
    &   \multirow{3}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts}
        & m3    & s3    & p3    & r3    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & Evolutionary game.    
                &   \multirow{6}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts.}
                        & Utility function.    
                                & \multirow{6}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts}   \\      \cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
\multirow{7}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts}
    &   \multirow{6}{=}{Text Text Text Text Text Texts}
        & \multirow{4}{=}{Bankruptcy game}    
                &       & Text Text Text Text Text Texts.    
                                &       \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m6    & s6    & p6    & r6    \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & m7    & s7    & p7    & r7    \\ \cline{2-6}
    & User vs Net
        & m8    & s8    & p8    & r8    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

In comparison to your MWE the following changes are done:

- removed are `makcell` comands from column headers
- all `multirow`s have `=` option for cells format
- number of text lines in spanned rows by `multirow` is adopted to their actual numbers
- `tabularx` table had to have at least one `X` column, in above table are now used three such columns
- increased is `\textwidth` by use of the package `geometry`
- added are missed packages

Comment: Currently, the column header alignment looks a bit unusual. Probably you also want to remove the `\multirow` command from the first header in order to ensure all headers are top aligned.

Comment: @leandriis, you are right. Corrected.  `\multirow` in the first table cell is removed.